# Calling a method on a new instance of an object without assigning it to a variable

Tags: python

I wrote the following code:

```
import random
class Point(object):    
    x = 0.0    
    def __init__(self, x): self.x = x            
    def shuffle(self): self.x = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

a = Point(0.0).shuffle()
print('a', a)

b = Point(0.0)
b.shuffle()
print('b', b)
```

It returns:

```
('a', None)
('b', <__main__.Point object at 0x00000000024FB710>)
```

Something went wrong with `a`: how can I call a method (here `shuffle()`) on a new instance (`a`)) of an object (`Point`) without assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is going to print `None` because `shuffle` doesn't return anything.  In Python, functions that don't return anything return `None` by default.  Furthermore, by doing:

```
print a
```

you are telling Python to print the return value of invoking the `shuffle` method.

To fix the problem, have `shuffle` return something (in this case, I think you want to make it return `self`).

Also, just a tip:  Judging by your `print` syntax, you are using Python 3.x.  In Python 3.x., there is no need to have classes inherit from `object`.  You only did that in Python 2.x. to make the classes "new-style" classes.  However, in Python 3.x., *all* classes are "new-style".

Comment: I'm actually using Python 2.7 but trying to get used to Python 3.x's `print` syntax. I didn't know there is no more need for `object` in Python 3.x, that's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply return `self` from the `shuffle` method.

```
import random
class Point(object):    
    x = 0.0    
    def __init__(self, x): self.x = x            
    def shuffle(self): 
        self.x = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
        return self

a = Point(0.0).shuffle()
print('a', a) #prints ('a', <__main__.Point object at 0x612850>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result of calling `shuffle` to `a`.

`shuffle` returns `None` in code you wrote.

Instead do:

```
def shuffle(self): 
    self.x = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    return self
```